# parsing process ID/names from /proc, thread IDs

Tags: process, python, proc, ps

When I'm parsing process IDs from /proc, obviously each thread of a process gets its own ID. And I realize that all the threads in that same process can be gathered from `/proc/${pid}/task/`.

But my question is, can I assume that the first ID in the list (the lowest numbered one?) is the main thread of the process?

The goal I'm ultimately trying to do is write a quick `ps` script in python without using a subprocess or invoking the shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assume that, process ids (and thread ids) can be reused, so the ordering is not guaranteed. (That's not likely on a freshly booted 64bit system, but you'll see it on machines with large uptimes.)

You can get the thread group id (which is the process id) from the `/proc/${id}/status`. It's in the line `Tgid: nnnnn`.

Ex:

```
$ cat /proc/8288/status 
Name:   vlc
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   8281               // main vlc process id
Pid:    8288               // thread id
```

Comment: That's a good point about reuse of pids. Don't know why I didn't think of that. This IS on an embedded, long running system. But new processes should very rarely be spawned anyway. However /proc/${pid}/task will include the thread pid. So if /proc/1/task has entries "1, 3, 5". /proc/3/task/ will also contain "1, 3, 5". So you can't assume that ${pid} is the main process ID.

Comment: you're right, I didn't think it did that but it does. Updated with another possibility.

Comment: That's probably the best I'll be able to get. It's not all that important anyway. So good enough =]